# Как достать переменную из функции Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана структура:

```
m = 0
def a():
    i = 2
```

Как можно вытащить переменную i из функции и ее переприсвоить m?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У функций своя область видимости, получить доступ к внутренним переменным из вне не получится. Но функция может возвращать значение/значения

```
def a():
    i = 2
    return i

m = a()
```

Answer (score 4):

Немного странный вариант через глобальные переменные:

```py
i = 10
def a():
    global i
    i = 2
a() # i вместо 10 равно 2.
```